# Graph of $e^{x^e}$ and $e^{x^k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I've been playing with some graphs involving Euler's constant, $e$, and I have noticed that the graph of $e^{x^e}$ (and other multiples/exponents for
$e$ in $x^e$) is only defined for positive values

[Graph of e^x^e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMbYY.png)

while other values of $k$ for $e^{x^k}$ with $k \neq$ a multiple/power of $e$ seems to be defined on all real numbers. Does someone have an explanation for this?

Comment: try k=1/2. Your conjecture is wrong

Comment: This boils down to the question whether you can define $x\mapsto x^k$ as a real-valued function on the whole of $\mathbb R$ when $k$ is not a non-negative integer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you explain how exponentiation works for non-integer numbers, namely irrational ones? I don't understand why $x^e$ can't be defined on all real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is wrong. For example, let $k=-1$. Then
$$f(x)=e^{x^k}=e^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ is not well defined in all $\mathbb{R}$. In fact you can choose any $k<0$ and notice the same.

If you want explore where are defined different functions you must read about the domain of the functions and the domain of their basic operations as sum, product, quotient and composition.

**A little Comment about why $x^e$ is not defined in all $\mathbb{R}$**

The exact reason is a little hard to explain (at least for me), but probably this comment help you to get a little of intuition about this fact. Consider the function $f(x)=x^r$ for a rational number $r$. Clearly, in general the function $f(x)$ is not a polynomial, for instance take $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and you get $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ which is not a polyomial (and in fact is not well defined in $x<0$). Thus, in general if $r=\frac{a}{b}$ then $f(x)=x^r=\sqrt[b]{x^a}$ and notice that the square root is not well defined for all $x<0$ (this may depend of the parity of $a$ and $b$). In particular, you can think that a similar situation occur when you have a function of the form $f(x)=x^l$ where $l$ is an irrational number.
To show that $x^e$ is not well defined in $x<0$, probably might help the following

We use the Taylor expansion of $f(x)=e^x$ at $x=1$. So, we get $$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$ Thus by the exponent laws $$f(x)=x^e=x^{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}}=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Finally, notice that to get the domain of the product $f(x)=x^e$ we must focus in calculate a domain to each $g_n(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n!}}$ , which implies try to find a domain of a product of all the functions $g_n(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n!}}$. In this part we must try search for one pattern or property of the domain of a product of functions (hint the domain of a product is the intersection of the domains of their components).
So is sufficient find a $n$ such that $g_n(x)$ is not well defined in $x<0$.

I hope this last comment help you to at least try to understand the intuition behind these fact.

Comment: Oh, I see. But why is $x^e$ not defined on all real numbers, then?